# Angular 5 issue with a named outlet children component

Tags: routes, components, angular5, children

I am quite new in Angular 5 and I am trying to do my first routing.
Here the situation.
I have the app.component as root component and others three different component that I would like to "drive" by angular routing system, here the html code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet name="mainContentOutlet"></router-outlet>
  <!--<app-xsoccer-content></app-xsoccer-content>-->
</div>
<div id="divider" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="footer-divider"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-xsoccer-footer></app-xsoccer-footer>
</div>
```

And here my routing table:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: XsoccerHeaderComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: BrowserMainMenuComponent},
        {path: 'home', component: BrowserHomeMenuComponent}
    ]},
    { path: '', component: XsoccerContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet', children: [
        {path: '', component: WelcomeContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet'},
        {path: 'home', component: HomeContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet'},
    ]},
    {path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent}
  ];
```

At application start the components: XsoccerHeaderComponent, BrowserMainMenuComponent, XsoccerContentComponent, WelcomeContentComponent are perfectly loaded and rendered.

But as soon as I click a login button, which I placed as BrowserMainMenuComponent's children I'm firing Router.navigate(['home']) from it, after having done some authentication logic; with the result that only BrowserHomeMenuComponent will be rendered while HomeContentComponent not.

Some of you guys can give any help please.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You cant have 2 blank routes on the top level of routes, try swapping the line `{ path: '', component: XsoccerContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet', children: [` with something like `{ path: 'content', component: XsoccerContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet', children: [`. Then call it with `this.router.navigate(['/content/home'])`

Comment: what doesnt work about it? can you be more specific?

Comment: Sure, in 'path' label I replaced the root (' ') route with 'content' route, but nothing happens, actually the application doesn't even load the welcome component at start. I attached an image to next poste about my problem (Angular 5 issue with a named outlet children component
(resprise)), maybe it can be more effective and clarify what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks a lot anyway.