# Angular 5 issue with a named outlet children component (reprise)

Tags: routes, components, angular5, children

Thanks a lot for help to mast3rd3mon about my question, but unfortunately with no luck. Perhaps if I upload a schema of what I'm trying to do can clear my problem and specify more precisely what I have in mind.

My HTML code of app.component.html

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet name="mainContentOutlet"></router-outlet>
  <!--<app-xsoccer-content></app-xsoccer-content>-->
</div>
<div id="divider" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="footer-divider"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-xsoccer-footer></app-xsoccer-footer>
</div>
```

And here my routing table:

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: XsoccerHeaderComponent, children: [
        {path: '', component: BrowserMainMenuComponent},
        {path: 'home', component: BrowserHomeMenuComponent}
    ]},
    { path: '', component: XsoccerContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet', children: [
        {path: '', component: WelcomeContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet'},
        {path: 'home', component: HomeContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet'},
    ]},
    {path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent}
  ];
```

Here my hand drawing, circled number are standing to indicate the sequence with which I would like to render things landing on application and after login.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OtLY.jpg)

Thanks again.

Comment: Hmm I think you need to add a `<router-outlet>` to `XsoccerContentComponent` and use it as the outlet for children. I'm not sure if you need to name the outlet for children.

Comment: Thank you Johnny but it doesn't work yet. I rearranged my layout a bit along with routing table, but still I'm not reach what I want......

Comment: .......My new layout: <div class="container-fluid">
  <!--<router-outlet></router-outlet>-->
  <app-xsoccer-header></app-xsoccer-header>
</div>
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
  <!--<router-outlet name="mainContentOutlet"></router-outlet>-->
  <app-xsoccer-content></app-xsoccer-content>
</div>
<div id="divider" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="footer-divider"></div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <app-xsoccer-footer></app-xsoccer-footer>
</div> ......

Comment: .....and routing table: const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: BrowserMainMenuComponent},
  { path: 'home', component: BrowserHomeMenuComponent },
  { path: '', component: WelcomeContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeContentComponent, outlet: 'mainContentOutlet' },
  { path: '**', component: PagenotfoundComponent }
];

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 issue with a named outlet children component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50005853/angular-5-issue-with-a-named-outlet-children-component)

Comment: This is a reprise, because I didn't know how I could modify it in order to put an image.